# Doubt in Continuity Correction

Tags: mathematical-statistics

In this question -

Let us say the mean number of Gems per packet is 20, and the variance is 2. Assuming that the distribution of Gems in the packet is Gaussian, what is the probability of finding a packet with 19 gems or fewer?

Should we take into account continuity correction and hence, the answer is p(z < (19.5-20) / √2) ?